# add toggle image button javascript to cms page

Tags: javascript, jquery, content-management-system, toggle

I want to add toggle image button `javascript` to `cms` page..

My websit

click the button -> dropdown hiden image in the my homepage index

this is possible ?

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#slide1 ").click(function() {
      $("#slide2 ").slideToggle(1000);
    });
  });
</script>

<a href="
http: /microwave.com/skin/frontend/default/MAG090198_Layout2/js/slide.js" id="slide1"> 
  Click to Slide Toggle milliseconds </a>
<br>
<br>
<p id="slide2" style="width:100%;display:block;background:red;height:180px">This is demo paragraph for slide functionality.</p>
```

```html
<div class="content-top">
  <div class="left-category">{{block type="catalog/navigation" template="advancedmenu/top.phtml"}}{{block type="catalog/navigation" template="catalog/navigation/sidenavigation.phtml"}}</div>
  <div class="home-slider">
    <div id="ei-slider" class="ei-slider">
      <ul class="ei-slider-large">
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img alt="" src="{{skin url=images/banners/main-banner1.jpg}}" />
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img alt="" src="{{skin url=images/banners/Untitled-15.jpg}}" />
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img alt="" src="{{skin url=images/banners/Untitled-16.jpg}}" />
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img alt="" src="{{skin url=images/banners/black.jpg}}" />
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img alt="" src="{{skin url=images/banners/asd.jpg}}" />
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img alt="" src="{{skin url=images/banners/123456.jpg}}" />
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="ei-slider-thumbs">
        <li class="ei-slider-element">Current</li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img alt="" src="{{skin url=images/banners/main-banner1.jpg}}" /><span class="info1">Cavity</span> 
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img alt="" src="{{skin url=images/banners/Untitled-15.jpg}}" /><span class="info1">Ceramic</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img alt="" src="{{skin url=images/banners/Untitled-16.jpg}}" /><span class="info1">Divider</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img alt="" src="{{skin url=images/banners/black.jpg}}" /><span class="info1">Amplifiers</span> 
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img alt="" src="{{skin url=images/banners/asd.jpg}}" /><span class="info1">Fiber Optic</span> 
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img alt="" src="{{skin url=images/banners/123456.jpg}}" /><span class="info1">Passive acc</span> 
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="mainslice">
  <a href="http:/
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Rajesh i'm trying my homepage img box 'Terminator' click -> all that drop the hidden menu showing bottom..